# Separate strings with semicolon and delimiter and containing parentheses

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I need to separate strings with semicolon (`;`) as delimiter. The semicolon inside parenthesis should be ignored.

Example:

```
string inputString = "(Apple;Mango);(Tiger;Horse);Ant;Frog;";
```

The output list of strings should be:

```
(Apple;Mango)
(Tiger;Horse)
Ant
Frog
```

The other valid input strings can be :

```
string inputString = "The fruits are (mango;apple), and they are good"
```

The above string should split to a single string

```
"The fruits are (mango;apple), and they are good"

string inputString = "The animals in (African (Lion;Elephant) and Asian(Panda; Tiger)) are endangered species; Some plants are endangered too."
```

The above string should split to two strings as shown below:

```
"The animals in (African (Lion;Elephant) and Asian(Panda; Tiger)) are endangered species"
"Some plants are endangered too."
```

I searched a lot but could not find the answer to the above scenario.

Does anybody know how to achieve this without reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Appreciate your prompt reply. Can you give an example?

Comment: Is there are reason you are using a semicolon for a delimiter? Your structure is very close to [JSON](http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp), so why not just use that?  Nothing against regex, because that would work too, I am just a standards proponent.

Comment: [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match) is some regex examples.

Comment: @iMortalitySX: That is how I get the input strings and I don't have the authority to change that.

Comment: @user1571734 Gotcha, just to be clear though, are there any cases where you would have parenthesis object inside another parethesis object?  e.g. "(Apple;(Mango;Pear));(Tiger;Horse);Ant;Frog;"

Comment: @iMortalitySX The input strings as of now don't contain nested parenthesis with semicolon inside them (there are nested parenthesis though), but this scenario can not be ignored or else it might create bugs in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression that matches what you want to keep, not the separators:

```
string inputString = "(Apple;Mango);(Tiger;Horse);Ant;Frog;";

MatchCollection m = Regex.Matches(inputString, @"\([^;)]*(;[^;)]*)*\)|[^;]+");

foreach (Match x in m){
  Console.WriteLine(x.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
(Apple;Mango)
(Tiger;Horse)
Ant
Frog
```

Expression comments:

```
\(           opening parenthesis
[^;)]*       characters before semicolon
(;[^;)]*)*   optional semicolon and characters after it
\)           closing parenthesis
|            or
[^;]+        text with no semicolon
```

Note: The expression above also accepts values in parentheses without a semicolon, e.g. `(Lark)` and mulitple semicolons, e.g. `(Lark;Pine;Birch)`. It will also skips empty values, e.g. `";;Pine;;;;Birch;;;"` will be two items, not ten.

Comment: The above regex splitted the text "The fruits are (mango;apple), and they are good" to two strings. Actually, it should have been one.

Comment: @user1571734: I see, changed specifications. ;) Add conditonal sets before and after the parentheses, and repeat the parentheses and the set after it: `@"[^;]*\(([^;)]*(;[^;)]*)*\)[^;]*)+|[^;]+"`.

Comment: @Guffa, you are aware that your regex is exactly equivalent to the somewhat simpler `([^;]|[(][^)]*[)])*`, right? Although that won't do the updated spec, either: regular expressions can't count, so nested parentheses aren't possible. (Mind you, there are so many irregular extensions in regexen that I don't really know what is and isn't possible. But nested parentheses is usually a sign that you need a real parser.)

Answer (score 0):

Handle the paranthesized case separately from the "normal" case, to ensure that semicolons are omitted in the former.

A regex to achieve this (matching a single element in your input) may look like the following (not tested):

```
"\([A-Za-z;]+\)|[A-Za-z]+"
```